# How to cleanup setTimeout/setInterval in event handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I clean up function like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` in event handler in React? Or is this unnecessary to do so?

```js
import React from 'react'

function App(){
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('you have clicked me')
        //How to clean this up?
      }, 500)
    }}>Click me</button>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 3):

Whether it's necessary depends on what the callback does, but certainly if the component is unmounted it almost doesn't matter what it does, you do need to cancel the timer / clear the interval.

To do that in a function component like yours, you use a `useEffect` cleanup function with an empty dependency array. You probably want to store the timer handle in a `ref`.

(FWIW, I'd also define the function outside of the `onClick` attribute, just for clarity.)

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

function App() {
    const instance = useRef({timer: 0});

    useEffect(() => {
        // What you return is the cleanup function
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(instance.current.timer);
        };
    }, []);

    const onClick = () => {
        // Clear any previous one (it's fine if it's `0`,
        // `clearTimeout` won't do anything)
        clearTimeout(instance.current.timer);
        // Set the timeout and remember the value on the object
        instance.current.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('you have clicked me')
            //How to clean this up?
        }, 500);
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    )
}

export default App;
```

An object you store as a ref is usually a useful place to put things you would otherwise have put on `this` in a class component.

(If you want to avoid re-rendering `button` when other state in your component changes (right now there's no other state, so no need), you could use `useCallback` for `onClick` so `button` always sees the same function.)

Comment: Hi T.J, Any benefits of storing timer id as a ref instead of a regular variable?

Comment: @AmirSaleem - You mean a local variable in the function? Yes, that won't work reliably. :-) The function is called any time React needs to re-render the component, and a local variable gets recreated every time the function is called, whereas the instance from `useRef` is stable. With a local, if the component were re-rendered even once prior to the button getting clicked, the `useEffect` callback would close over a stale copy of the variable, not the one the button is setting. (Because only the first version of the `useEffect` callback is ever used, because of the empty dependency array.)

Comment: *(Oops, had a typo in the answer above. If you see `instance.timer` rather than `instance.current.timer`, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Thanks T.J. for your detailed explanation. This was insightful

Comment: @T.J.Crowder do you clear *every* timer (that use `setState()`) in event handler? I haven't done so until I came across a "setState on unmounted" warning. I also come across [this discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82) that claims the warning isn't needed. Now I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa - Yes, I do, and I recommend doing so, just on the general principle of doing clean up. For a one-off timer (`setTimeout`), it's not that big a deal (which is part of why they've removed the warning), since the call to the state setter will just be ignored and the timer only fires once. For an interval timer, it's important, because even though the state setter calls will be ignored, the timer will keep running until the page unloads. It's easy enough to build a `useTimer` hook so you don't have to worry about the details every time. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Clear timer when unmount component

```js
import React from 'react'

function App(){
  const timerRef = React.useRef(null)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
     // clean
      timerRef.target && clearTimeout(timerRef.target)
    }
  },[])
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      timerRef.target = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('you have clicked me')
      }, 500)
    }}>Click me</button>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Two problems with the above: 1. **Every** instance of `App` will share the **same** `timer` variable, which is a massive no-no. :-) 2. You're missing the empty dependency array on the `useEffect` call, so it will call that cleanup function every time the component is about to be re-rendered, not just when the component is unmounted.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, my bad, I have fixed it.

Comment: `.target` should be `.current` in your latest version.

Answer (score -1):

One more solution ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-callback-timer-208x0?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncCallback } from "use-async-effect2";
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const click = useAsyncCallback(function* (ms) {
    yield CPromise.delay(ms);
    setText("done!" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo:</div>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <button onClick={() => click(2000)}>Click me!</button>
      <button onClick={click.cancel}>Cancel scheduled task</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In case if you want to cancel the previous pending task ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-callback-timer-single-39b4b?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncCallback } from "use-async-effect2";
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const click = useAsyncCallback(
    function* (ms) {
      console.log("click");
      yield CPromise.delay(ms);
      setText("done!" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    },
    { deps: [], cancelPrevios: true }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo:</div>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <button onClick={() => click(5000)}>Click me!</button>
      <button onClick={click.cancel}>Cancel scheduled task</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```