# How do I stop the recording automatically after 15 seconds if the user hasn't stopped the recording?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [recording, setRecording] = React.useState();

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log('Requesting permissions..');
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

      console.log('Starting recording..');
      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync( Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log('Recording started');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    console.log('Stopping recording..');
    setRecording(undefined);
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: false,
    });
    const uri = recording.getURI();
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={recording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
      /> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

The code I have records audio when the button is pressed, and stops recording when the button is pressed again. How do I modify the code to stop the recording automatically once it has reached 15 seconds if the user hasn't already pressed the button to stop it?

Comment: Probably you can add `setTimeout(() => stopRecording(), 15000)` to the body of your startRecording function.

Comment: You may also want to stop the timer if the user manually stops the recording prior to 15 seconds, as well as [clean up your timer in the event your component is unmounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072320/how-to-cleanup-settimeout-setinterval-in-event-handler-in-react)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `setTimeout`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (recording) {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      stopRecording()
    }, 15000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}, [recording])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a timeout of 15 seconds which calls the stopRecording function if it is still recording.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  stopRecording();
}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `setTimeout` function.

The documentation can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

For your use case, you would create a new function to handle a 15-second recording. It might look something like this:

```
async function recordFor15Seconds() {
  startRecording();
  setTimeout(() => {
    stopRecording();
  }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: This cannot work since the second argument is a string

Comment: @devpolo ah that was a mistake, I will edit. It will actually work due to type coercion, but you are right in that it is not good practice.